# How to get subsets of a set with given number of elements in C with recursion?

Tags: c, recursion

For instance when user input 4 and 2, it means the original set have 4 elements: (1,2,3,4) and the subset should have 2 elements. I figured out a way to present these subsets in a regular form like (1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(2,3)(2,4)(3,4) using the code below, but my assignment requires binary-like form like (1,2) should be (1,1,0,0) and (2,4) should be (0,1,0,1) etc. In (1,1,0,0), first binary 1 means the first element in original set (1,2,3,4) which is 1 is contained in the subset. And the second binary 1 means the second element in original set which is 2 is contained in subset. While the third and forth number 3 and 4 is not. So for example, a subset (1,2,5) from set (1,2,3,4,5) can be presented by (1,1,0,0,1)

```
void subset(int n, int k, int B[], int q, int r) {
    if (q == k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            printf("%d ", B[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        for (int i = r; i < n; i++) {
            B[q] = i+1;
            subset(n, k, B, q+1, i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

In main (n is number of elements in original set, k is number of elements in subsets):

```
int B[101];
subset(n, k, B, 0, 0);
```

Also my assignment needs this recursive function with 4 exact arguments( i is from (1,2,3,4...i) ):

```
void subsets(int B[], int n, int k, int i)
```

I've tried so many ways and failed. I'll be really appreciated if someone can help me out, thanks.

**Updates:**
thanks to rajender kumar, the binary-like output problem is solved by using the code below:

```
void printSubsets(int B[], int n, int k, int q, int i) {
    if (q == k) {
        int finalArry[MAX_SIZE+1] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            finalArry[B[i]] = 1;
        }
        printSet(finalArry, n);

    } else {
        for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            B[q] = j+1;
            printSubsets(B, n, k, q+1, j+1);
        }
    }
}
```

But I still need to remove one argument from either int q or int i.

Comment: How does `(1,2)` become `(1,1,0,0)`?

Comment: In (1,1,0,0), first binary 1 means the first element in original set (1,2,3,4) which is 1 is contained in the subset. And the second binary 1 means the second element in original set which is 2 is contained in subset. While the third and forth number 3 and 4 is not. So for example, a subset (1,2,5) from set (1,2,3,4,5) can be presented by (1,1,0,0,1).

Comment: Hint: there are three conditions that need to be handled in the recursive function: `i == n`, `k < n-i`, and `k > 0`. The first is the base case. The other two determine whether a particular recursive call is made.

Comment: I don't really get the last two conditions. Is there any way you can fix my code? Thanks

Comment: chajie2000 Please [edit] your question to explain everything inside, instead of hiding helpful information in comments.

Comment: More Hint: The fourth argument `i` could be the deepness of the recursion. You are allowed to call `subset` twice in the recursive function. Enough said I think :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
void subset(int n, int k, int B[], int i) {
    if (k == 0) {
        for (int d = 0; d < n; d++) {
            printf("%d ", B[d]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else if (i >= n || k > n - i) {
        return;
    } else {
        B[i] = 1;
        subset(n, k - 1, B, i + 1);
        B[i] = 0;
        subset(n, k, B, i + 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n, k;
    int B[4];

    memset(B, 0, sizeof(B));
    n = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
    k = 2;
    printf("n=%d\nk=%d\n", n, k);
    subset(n, k, B, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another boolean array and put entire array like this .

```
void subset(int n, int k, int B[], int q, int r) {
    if (q == k) {
        bool finalArry[n] = {0};
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                finalArry[B[i]-1] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(finalArry[i]){
                cout<<1<<" ";
            }
            else{
                cout<<0<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;

    } else {
        for (int i = r; i < n; i++) {
            B[q] = i+1;
            subset(n, k, B, q+1, i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems doesn't work. I’ve tried something like this before but the results are all 1 except the first few subsets.

Comment: can you show me for which input behaviour is not expected as mentioned ?

Comment: Sorry actually this bool method worked but the problem is I have five arguments passed in and I need to cut it down to 4. Details about it is in original post.